# Google OAuth pushing a Http redirect instead of Https with ASP MVC .Net 7 App (NGINX reverse proxy)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, nginx

Added an ASP MVC .NET application on Centos with CWP.
I want the application on the Centos server to run on the HTTP scheme/protocol, for any outward-facing or incoming traffic it should use HTTPS.

I am using NGINX as the proxy it is setup like this:

[image]

For sake of testing I SSH into the server and startup the application:
[image]

It started on port http://localhost:5000

Every page I browse on the domain is https, as soon  as I browse to google to sign in (google oAuth) it give the error:

> Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

[image]

To try and combat the this I have the force-https,
I changed the nginix config file directly:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name abc.com www.abc.com;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

I added this line of code to my application [code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio%2Clinux-ubuntu):

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

Im trying to understand why it is still sending a https request instead of a http request?
I did double check that the redirect urls are the same in Google Console